# How to escape special characters in cscope "Find this egrep pattern"

Tags: cscope

How does one escape special characters in the cscope "Find this egrep pattern" ?
For instance I want to find everywhere in a huge codebase where I have the statement

```
print("\n[<something>.....
```

I need to find every line where a print format specifier string has a newline immediately followed by a left bracket character.

How do I feed this to the egrep pattern search?

I tried:

```
Find this egrep pattern: \\n[
Find this egrep pattern: \\n\[
```

got :

```
Egrep Syntax error in this pattern: \n[
Could not find the egrep pattern: \\n\[
```

Answer (score 0):

I use cscope version 15.8b, using the pattern `\\n\[` will match the string you want.

P.S., the "egrep" in cscope might confuse us. As the [bugzilla page](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=163330) I googled, it is a little implementation of "extended" regular expression, its behavior might be not the same with `egrep` util of Linux command line.

Answer (score 0):

Place the special characters to be searched within **[ ]** brackets.

Example:

Find this egrep pattern:

> **print[("\]n**